# Poisson's equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

By definition $\{ {w_k}\} _{k = 1}^\infty \ $ is an orthorgonal basis in $H_0^1(U)$ and an orthornomal basis in $L^2(U)$.

suppose $f \in {L^2}(U)$ and assume that ${u_m} = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^m {d_m^k{w_k}}$ solves

$$\int\limits_U {D{u_m} \cdot D{w_k}dx = } \int\limits_U {f \cdot {w_k}dx}  $$ for $k=1,2,\cdots\ m$.

Show that a subsequence of $\{ {u_m}\} _{m = 1}^\infty $converges weakly in $H_0^1$ to the weak solution of

$$\left\{\begin{align*}
&- \Delta u = f&&\text{in }U\\
&u = 0&&\text{on }\partial U
\end{align*} \right.$$

Actually I know that we can according to the usual energy estimation  to obtain the subsequence, and integrate by parts,while I still don't konw how to pass to limit to in the integrating equation.Wish to somebody to give the details, Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think weak convergence in $H_0^1$ exactly means that the integrals involving $u_m$ will converge.... By the way, what are $w_k$ and $d_m^k$?

Comment: As stated it is false. You really **must** give all details, including what $d^k_m$ and $w_k$ are. Counterexample to the current version: let $w_k \equiv 1$ (assuming $U$ is bounded open) and $f \equiv 0$. Then $d^k_m = \delta_{km}$ certainly leads to $u$ that satisfy the integral equation. The only weak solution to Laplace's equation with Dirichlet boundary conditions is $u\equiv 0$. But all our $u_m \equiv 1$.

Comment: My best guess is that you want $w_k$ to be some basis functions for $L^2(U)$ and $d^k_m$ are coefficients of approximate solutions? Your formulation reminds me a bit of finite element methods.

Comment: @FengxiaoHe Please add the missing information to the question by clicking `edit` under it. It should not be left in the comment thread only. While doing so, you should clarify what kind of basis the functions $w_k$ form (orthogonal, orthonormal,...?)